# CKEDITOR - enable inserting Java Script code

Tags: javascript, onclick, ckeditor

I use CKEDITOR in my web application.

What I need is that the user can insert images which have an "onClick" property.

I tested it and I noticed that the editor erases the full "onClick" property including the whole javascript code.
The JS code behind "onClick" opens a new window ("window.open(...);").

Is there a way to allow such things by editing the CKEDITOR config file?

Thanks in advance

Tommy

Comment: Have you seen the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the issue I was having. CKEditor was stripping my JS code in the WYSIWYG. Here was my solution, and please be very careful as allowing people to enter script to your page WILL open you to potential attack. I didn't want people to be able to enter JS code with the editor but I needed the JS code to display a HTML developed Flowchart for the site. 
I use CKEditor to allow staff to contribute to procedures and processes and save the work to a DB using PHP. On the final page that everyone else accesses I just echo what has been developed with CKEditor with PHP. My solution was just to add the JS code after I echo the PHP query result.

```
<tr>
<td>
<!--echo out the result of the work done with CKEditor-->
<?php echo $ckedit_result;?>
<!--Add what ever JS Code you need to have loaded-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https:whatever your JS code is"></script>
</td>
</tr>
```

Worked a treat